# enable an input field on confirm true return

Tags: jquery, html

I want to enable a input field which is for picking date of payment only if a payment checkbox is checked! clicking on the checkbox triggers a confirmation question for payment and if confirmed the checkbox is checked and the input box will be editable!
here is the code that is not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#talk").click(function(){
       return confirm("Did you pay the tax?");
      var isChecked = $('#talk').is(':checked');
      if(isChecked==true)
      {

        $("#paydate").html('<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter the Date!" />');
      }
    });
  });
</script>

<div id="paydate">
<input type="checkbox" id="talk" />
<input type="text" id="name" readonly />
</div>
```

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need to recreate your element.
just remove the `readonly` attribute:

```
$("#talk").click(function() {
    var isChecked = $('#talk').is(':checked');
    if (isChecked == true) {
        if (confirm("Did you pay the tax?")) {
            $('#name').removeAttr('readonly')
        }
    }
});
```

to lock the checkbox, as you commented, add `$(this).prop('disabled',true)` after `$('#name').removeAttr('readonly')`

Comment: Yes but I also need to lock the checkbox once it is checked!

Comment: @Distributor: what if the user made a mistake and want to uncheck it? anyway, updated my answer to show you how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(isChecked==true)
      {
        var a = confirm("Did you pay the tax?");
        if(a == true){
          $("#paydate").html('<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter the Date!" />');
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#talk").click(function(){
      var isChecked = $('#talk').is(':checked');
      if(isChecked==true)
      {
       if(confirm("Did you pay the tax?"))
        $("#paydate").html('<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter the Date!" 

/>');
      }
    });
  });
</script>

<div id="paydate">
<input type="checkbox" id="talk" />
<input type="text" id="name" readonly />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#talk").click(function(){
      var isChecked = $('#talk').is(':checked');

      if(isChecked==true)
      {
        if(confirm("Did you pay the tax?"))
        $("#paydate").html('<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter the Date!" />');
      }
    });
  });
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/EH6CG/